# Web-mode does not load in emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm pretty new to emacs and I'm currently trying to configure it properly for my needs, but I can't make it load `web-mode` at all.

So, this is what I've done:

1. Downloaded [`web-mode.el` from GitHub](https://raw.github.com/fxbois/web-mode/master/web-mode.el)
2. Made sure the file is located in the correct directory: `~/.emacs.d/web-mode.el`
3. Used the installation instructions from the [official page](http://web-mode.org)

My `.emacs` file now looks [like this](http://pastebin.com/rR8jqbmj)

Issue:

When I'm trying to edit any of the file types specified in the `.emacs` file, it only runs the default modes. PHP Abbrev for PHP etc... I'm not receiving any error messages and when I'm running `--debug-init` it does not give any output.

Emacs version: GNU Emacs 23.1.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.18.9) of 2012-03-01 on sl6.fnal.gov

OS: Scientific Linux

Does anyone know how I can troubleshoot this further, or have solved similar issues?

Comment: Well there are a few less-than-ideal things about that config, but it should work, so let's sort that out first. Are you sure this .emacs is actually being loaded? Type `C-h v user-init-file RET` and check that it's the expected path. Or if you type `C-h e` to switch to the messages buffer, you can check for confirmation that it loaded the web-mode.el library as expected.

Comment: You can also start emacs with `emacs --no-start-file --no-site-lisp` to eliminate any site-wide init files that might interfere with your own config.

Comment: let me try: remove the line `(load "~/.emacs.d/web-mode.el")` and put `(require 'web-mode)` instead.

Comment: What happens if you manually switch to `web-mode`, e.g. `M-x web-mode`?

Comment: Thanks for all these replies guys. I'll try to answer them all:

Comment: Thanks for all these replies guys. I'll try to answer them all:

@phils: The user-init-file command gives the following output:
Its value is
"/nfs/home/myuser/.emacs"

I guess that is correct. When running emacs --no-start-file --no-site-lisp Emacs gives the following: Unknown option `--no-start-file'

C-h e outputs: focus-init.el, php-mode-init.el, po-mode-init.el, puppet-mode-init.el, rpm-spec-mode-init.el. As you can see, it does not load web-mode.el.

@Ehvince: unfortunately nothing happend

@Chris: This seem to start the web-mode.

Comment: Um, is it correct, or isn't it? If you don't know the answer, type `M-x eval-expression RET (find-file user-init-file) RET` and confirm whether or not the file Emacs loads as a result is the .emacs file you've been editing.

Comment: The `--no-start-file` argument must be recent. I guess just `--no-site-lisp` should be sufficient to exclude unexpected configs, though.

Comment: At any rate, it seems that there *is* something other than the .emacs file you've showed us being loaded, as those libraries listed in your messages buffer at start-up are not part of Emacs and not part of that .emacs file.

Answer (score 1):

You should let `el-get` install it for you. El-get is a package manager for emacs. It can install packages from github, emacswiki, elpa, an url, … http://wikemacs.org/index.php/El-get

It's very handy, you can update scripts easily, it manages dependencies, it lets you discover many stuff, you can easily share your config accross machines, etc.

Emacs 24 has `package.el` or `ELPA` by default. One can install it on emacs 23, but my experience isn't conclusive so I'd advise sticking with el-get, which is great.

Answer (score 0):

In your .emacs file
PHP in web-mode does not work because of this line

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tpl\\.php\\'" . web-mode))
```

The problem here is that the .tpl and .php is together

You can split the two apart like in this lines of code

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tpl\\" . web-mode))
```

Or just remove the .tpl

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . web-mode))
```

I hope this helps!